# Is it possible to use a std::array as a data container for a POD struct?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, struct, embedded

I'm trying to update some legacy C code that uses an array as a data container with named access via macros to a more elegant C++17 solution (will be updated to C++20 when available, possible C++20 solutions are welcome). Sorry if there is a lot of code, but this is my first StackOverflow question suggestions regarding layout are welcome.

The current legacy C design:

```
#define WORD_ARR_SIZE   100
int16_t         word_arr[WORD_ARR_SIZE];    //two byte variables

#define var0        word_arr[0] //macros are used to hide the array and use its members like variables
#define myValue     word_arr[1]
#define myParameter word_arr[2]
#define free        ((uint16_t)word_arr[3]) //'hidden' explicit cast needed when using the array as all data must be of the same type
#define var1        word_arr[4]
#define var2        word_arr[5]
#define var3        word_arr[6]
#define var4        word_arr[7]
#define var5        word_arr[7] //very easy to write the wrong index when adding new 'variables'

extern int send(int16_t* arr, size_t size); //The array is necessary as it needs to be fed to a library (code cannot be modified)

int main()
{
    (uint16_t)var1 = UINT16_MAX; //'visible' explicit cast needed when using the array as all data is of the same type
    myValues = 50;

    for(int a = 20; a < 30; a++)
    {
        word_arr[a] = 10;   //array is also used like it should be
    }

    return send(word_arr, WORD_ARR_SIZE);
}
```

My first attempt at solving the problem was using a struct instead of an array, this removed the explicit casts and the need for macros, but had the disadvantage of missing the simple access via index that the array implementation had, replacing it with an ugly reinterpret_cast.

```
//no need for pragma pack, the code doesn't care about padding
struct word_arr_t
{
    int16_t var0;   //no more macros
    int16_t myValue;    
    int16_t myParameter;
    uint16_t free;   //no need for cast, value is alredy declared using the correct type
    int16_t var1;       
    int16_t var2;  //no way to get the index as if it was an array by simply using the value.
    int16_t var3;       
    int16_t var4;       
    int16_t var5;       
}word_arr;

constexpr size_t WORD_ARR_SIZE = sizeof(word_arr_t) / sizeof(uint16_t);

auto word_arr_p = reinterpret_cast<int16_t*>(&word_arr); //needed for indexed access

extern int send(int16_t* arr, size_t size);

int main()
{
    word_arr.var1 = UINT16_MAX;
    word_arr.myValues = 50;

    for(int a = 20; a < 30; a++)
    {
        word_arr_p[a] = 10;   //'hidden' pointer arithmetic to access the struct like an array
    }

    return send(word_arr_p, sizeof(word_arr_t));
}
```

The current solution:
I created a custom templated class called SmartStruct, I pass the struct type and values type in the template; I created an overload to operator[] allowing access via index hiding the ugly reinterpret_cast;

```
/**
 * \brief   A wrapper for structs made of object of the same type, allows indexed access
 * \tparam StructT  struct type
 * \tparam DataT    struct data type
 */
template <typename StructT, typename DataT>
class SmartStruct
{
    DataT* m_dataPointer;
public:
    /**
     * \brief let the struct be accessible from the outside as well
     */
    StructT Data;
    const size_t Count;

    /**
     * \brief Default constructor
     */
    SmartStruct();

    /**
     * \brief Construct by struct copy
     * \param data struct to copy
     */
    explicit SmartStruct(const StructT& data);

    /**
     * \brief operator to access struct in array style 
     * \param index element to access
     * \return element, if index >= size then first element
     */
    DataT& operator[](size_t index);
};

template <typename StructT, typename DataT>
SmartStruct<StructT, DataT>::SmartStruct() : Data{}, Count{ sizeof Data / sizeof(DataT) }
{
    m_dataPointer = reinterpret_cast<DataT*>(&Data);
}

template <typename StructT, typename DataT>
SmartStruct<StructT, DataT>::SmartStruct(const StructT& data) : Count{ sizeof data / sizeof(DataT) }
{
    //copy the struct
    Data = data;
    m_dataPointer = reinterpret_cast<DataT*>(&Data);
}

template <typename StructT, typename DataT>
DataT& SmartStruct<StructT, DataT>::operator[](size_t index)
{
    if (index >= Count)
    {
        return *m_dataPointer;
    }

    return m_dataPointer[index];
}
```

Usage example:

```
struct word_arr_t
{
    int16_t var0;
    int16_t myValue;
    int16_t myParameter;
    uint16_t free;
    int16_t var1;
    int16_t var2;
    int16_t var3; //Still no way to get array index from variable name
    int16_t var4;
    int16_t var5;
};

SmartStruct<word_arr_t, word> smart_word_arr{}; //Would love it if I could use std containers interface without having to implement it all by hand...


extern int send(int16_t* arr, size_t size);

int main()
{
    word_arr_t& word_arr = smart_word_arr.Data;

    word_arr.var1 = UINT16_MAX;
    word_arr.myValues = 50;

    for(int a = 20; a < 30; a++)
    {
        smart_word_arr[a] = 10;
    }

    return send(&smart_word_arr[0], smart_word_arr.Count);
}
```

Now that I got the context out of the way I can finally go to the real question:

**Would it be possible to use a std::array as a a data container for the struct?**
meaning initializing it via the struct; this would make it possible to access the data via variable using the struct itself and via index using std::array with the added bonus of a std interface without having to re-implement it.

My current attempt at getting this solution to work:

```
struct word_arr_t
{
    int16_t var0;
    int16_t myValue;
    int16_t myParameter;
    uint16_t free;
    int16_t var1;
    int16_t var2;
    int16_t var3; //Still no way to get array index from variable name
    int16_t var4;
    int16_t var5;
}word_struct;

std:.array<int16_t, sizeof(word_arr_t) / sizeof(word)> word_array{};
//std:.array<int16_t, sizeof(word_arr_t) / sizeof(word)> word_array{&word_struct}; would be lovely if I could do this.
//word_array.Data = reinterpret_cast<int16_t*>(&word_struct); this would also be good.

extern int send(int16_t* arr, size_t size);

int main()
{
    word_struct.var1 = UINT16_MAX;
    word_struct.myValues = 50;

    //copy struct into array, very very bad as it's not usable unless you know when
    //code writes to the struct and when code writes to the array,
    //this could be solved by wrapping the array into a read only object but still not ideal
    //and extremely slow especially if the struct is very large
    memcpy(word_array.Data, &word_struct, sizeof(word_struct));

    for(auto& a : word_array)
    {
        a = 10;
    }

    return send(word_array.Data, word_array.Size);
}
```

Comment: BTW, you calculation of `WORD_ARR_SIZE` is not correct.  Compilers are allowed to add padding bytes between members.

Comment: Because of possible padding between members of a `struct`, you can't treat the `struct` as an array; you'll have to use the "." operator to access the members, by name.

Comment: You could overload `operator[]` in your `struct` to return member variables.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews No need to worry about padding as the struct is always made out of types with the same size (two byte), the only padding that the compiler ever adds is 2 bytes and the end of the struct, I could also force a 2 byte pack to make sure the struct is of the size I want it to be in case the compiler decides to put some padding around the members.

Comment: You cannot guarantee in standard C++ that each member will be placed in consecutive locations.  Your compiler may have a `#pragma pack` or some similar `pragma` that will pack the members (e.g. place them in consecutive locations).  If you wish to have items in consecutive locations, the only guarantees are `std::vector`, `std::array` or an array.

Comment: I will pack the structs then, so they are aligned in memory, if a decide to keep using them this way.

Comment: Can you keep this part of the code as C? The correct solution in C is not this macro mess, but to use a `union`. That's far more elegant than anything else that can be done in either language and padding is not an issue here. Unfortunately, C++ is unsuitable for embedded systems since it doesn't allow union type punning, so it has to be written in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If compiling this part of the code as C is an option, then the most elegant solution by far is to use a `union`. Since alignment isn't an issue here and there will be no padding. This can be done in C only, which allows type punning through unions.

```
typedef union
{
  struct // C11 anonymous struct
  {
    int16_t  var0;
    int16_t  myValue;
    int16_t  myParameter,
    uint16_t free;
    int16_t  var1;
    int16_t  var2;
    int16_t  var3;
    int16_t  var4;
    // var5 not declared on purpose
  };

  int16_t arr [WORD_ARR_SIZE];

} word_t;
```

This is how the original C code should have been written. Here all type information and special cases are handled at compile-time, and type punning from `int16_t` to `uint16_t` is well-defined and their effective types alias.

You can make an `enum` for the special case `var5` indexing:

```
typedef enum
{
  var0_index = 0,
  myValue_index = 1,
  myParameter_index = 2,
  free_index = 3,
  var_1index = 4,
  var_2index = 5,
  var_3index = 6,
  var_4index = 7,
  var_5index = 7,
} var_t;

word_t word = 
{
  // different sorts of designated initializers can be mixed:
    .var0 = x,
  .myValue = y,      
  [var5_index] = z,
};
```

("word" is a horrible type/variable name though, since in computer science the term word refers to a complete integer type. So please come up with something better.)

Comment: I'm not actually the one that came up with the "word" name, those arrays in the code are called wordm, worde, wordi, wordo etc.. it is from a protocol that is 15+ years old and that is the convention in the library (WORD meaning an array made of 16bit values, there are also bytem, dwordm, qwordm etc...), I have to keep those names as senior users are very used to them; anyway I never would have thought about using a union as they are mostly useless in C++, having to compile the declarations of these structs in C is actually an advantage for me.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot treat separate variable as array.

Not ideal but you can have accessors, something like:

```
struct word_arr_t
{
    std::array<std::int16_t, 100> data{}; // your array

    int16_t& var0() { return data[0]; }
    int16_t& myValue()  { return data[1]; }    
    int16_t& myParameter { return data[2]; }
    uint16_t free() const { return static_cast<uint16_t>(data[3]); }
    void set_free(uint16_t value) { data[3] = static_cast<int16_t>(value); }
    int16_t& var1() { return data[4]; }
    int16_t& var2() { return data[5]; }
    int16_t& var3() { return data[6]; }
    int16_t& var4() { return data[7]; }
    int16_t& var5() { return data[8]; }
};

int main()
{
    word_arr_t word_arr;
    word_arr.var1() = INT16_MAX;
    word_arr.myValues() = 50;

    send(word_arr.data.data(), word_arr.data.size());
    // ...
}
```

or enum indexes:

```
enum Index
{
    var0,
    myValue,
    myParameter,
    free,
    var1,
    var2,
    var3,
    var4,
    var5,
};

struct word_arr_t
{
    std::array<std::int16_t, 100> data{}; // your array
};


int main()
{
    word_arr_t word_arr;
    word_arr.data[Index::var1] = INT16_MAX;
    word_arr.data[Index::myValues] = 50;

    send(word_arr.data.data(), word_arr.data.size());
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I like the first solution you proposed, it's not that ugly but what worries me is the way I am forced to use a get() and set() for values that I want to give a different type to, also calling a function is a little ugly but MUCH better then a macro; Regarding the second solution I would still have to rely on explicit casts when I want to assign a value of different type which I would really like to remove.

Comment: "You cannot treat separate variable as array." Sure you can, just not in C++.

Answer (score 0):

> Would it be possible to use a std::array as a a data container for the struct?

A [POD struct](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pod) in C++ is a class that is [trivial](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivial) and has [standard layout](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_standard_layout).
Starting with `std::array` as the underlying storage for a "struct" means you're not actually defining any `struct` with named members. You would have to write a class that contains the array and members that access indices of the array, and that can easily become *not trivial* and *not standard layout*.

By overloading `operator[]` you can access the "array" members of a struct with array-like syntax, while keeping the `struct` definition and POD status.

If it *looks* like a `struct` and `[]`'s like a `std::array`, then it's probably *good enough* as far as the end-user is concerned.

Here is an example program demonstrating that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <type_traits>

struct ArrPODStruct
{
    int someHeaderValue1;
    int someHeaderValue2;
    int someHeaderValue3;

    int a0;
    int a1;
    int a2;
    int a3;
    int a4;

    int operator[] (int i)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
            case 0: return a0;
            case 1: return a1;
            case 2: return a2;
            case 3: return a3;
            case 4: return a4;
            default: throw std::out_of_range("...");
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    ArrPODStruct arr;
    // Put some useful data in arr...

    std::cout << "Is POD: " << (std::is_pod<ArrPODStruct>() ? "Yes" : "No") << "\n";
    std::cout << "Element 0: " << arr.a0 << " or " << arr[0] << "\n";
    std::cout << "Element 1: " << arr.a1 << " or " << arr[1] << "\n";
    std::cout << "Element 2: " << arr.a2 << " or " << arr[2] << "\n";
    std::cout << "Element 3: " << arr.a3 << " or " << arr[3] << "\n";
    std::cout << "Element 4: " << arr.a4 << " or " << arr[4] << "\n";
}
```

**Output:**

```
Is POD: Yes
Element 0: 0 or 0
Element 1: 0 or 0
Element 2: 0 or 0
Element 3: 0 or 0
Element 4: 0 or 0
```

Comment: The operator[] is a really good solution I also did not know that adding an operator to a struct would still keep it a POD instead of a C++ object, the only downside is that i would still need to implement iterators by hand as I would like the struct to be used transparently into modern c++ code (for functions like std::accumulate, std::find I need iterators, which is why I would like std::array as an underlying container or interface).

Comment: This resolves everything in run-time though, it is branch-intensive and slow.

Comment: @Lundin, You're right, but the question doesn't specify any requirements about performance. My answer is pointing out what I believe would be the *nicest* way to solve the problem, in regards to saving the programmer work and typing.

Comment: @Project579, The "uglier" approach that I investigated before writing this answer was extending `std::array` with function members to access specific indices. `std::array<int16_t>` is a POD type.

Comment: "Slow but elegant" is C++ in a nutshell. The union version I posted as answer is superior to anything that can be done in C++, both in terms of speed and readability. It's a pure POD, no constructor bloat on start-up etc. Unfortunately, the C++ committee is full of PC people, so there's no type punning to be had in C++.

Comment: @Lundin, Unfortunately, the question *did* explicitly require a C++17 or C++20 solution because they are moving *away* from C. While my answer may not be using newer C++ features, an answer that suggests using C instead of C++ may not be what the OP wants. I like your answer though, and in many cases it makes sense to compile some C in a C++ project.